How to set custom tick labels in Plotly.Blazor
I've been struggling to understand how XAxis.TickText and XAxis.DTick work in Plotly.Blazor. I've been using the code in this question as a rough guide, but no matter what I do, the labels on the x-axis will not change. My current code looks like so:
@using Plotly.Blazor
@using Plotly.Blazor.Traces
@using Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib

<PlotlyChart @bind-bind-Config="config" @bind-bind-Layout="layout" @bind-Data="data" />

@code {
    string XAxisLabel = "Test Label";
    List<Point> Points = new List<Point>(new Point(0, 1, "Jan"), new Point(0.5, 1.1, "Feb"), new Point(1, 0.8, "Mar"));

    Config config = new Config();
    Layout layout = new Layout();

    IList<ITrace> data = new List<ITrace>();
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Scatter S = new Scatter();
        S.TextArray = new List<string>();
        S.Mode = Plotly.Blazor.Traces.ScatterLib.ModeFlag.Lines | Plotly.Blazor.Traces.ScatterLib.ModeFlag.Markers;
        S.X = new List<object>();
        S.Y = new List<object>();
        Dictionary<double, string> XAxisTicks = new Dictionary<double, string>();

        foreach (Point P in Points)
        {
            S.X.Add(P.x);
            S.Y.Add(P.y);
            S.TextArray.Add(P.PersonalLabel);
            if (!P.PersonalLabel.Equals(string.Empty)) XAxisTicks[P.x] = P.PersonalLabel;
            else if (!XAxisTicks.ContainsKey(P.x)) XAxisTicks[P.x] = P.x.ToString();
        }
        IList<object> IListLabels = new List<object>();
        IList<object> IListVals = new List<object>();
        foreach (string TickLabel in XAxisTicks.Values)
        {
            IListLabels.Add(TickLabel);
        }
        foreach (double TickVal in XAxisTicks.Keys)
        {
            IListVals.Add(TickVal);
        }

        layout.XAxis = new List<XAxis> { new() { Title = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.XAxisLib.Title { Text = XAxisLabel },
                                         DTick = 1,
                                         TickMode = Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.XAxisLib.TickModeEnum.Array,
                                         TickVals = IListVals,
                                         TickText = IListLabels } };
        data.Add(S);
    }
    
    public class Point
    {
        public double x;
        public double y;
        public string PersonalLabel = string.Empty;
        
        public Point()
        {
            x = 0.0;
            y = 0.0;
        }

        public Point(double xValue, double yValue, string Label)
        {
            x = xValue;
            y = yValue;
            PersonalLabel = Label;
        }
    }
}

However, despite IListLabels containing decidely non-numeric strings, the labels on the x-axis remain the same. Setting XAxis.DTick to 1 will not even remove the ticks whose values are not integers. I know that if my code setting XAxis.TickText worked, then setting XAxis.DTick to 1 wouldn't do anything, but it fails to accomplish anything even when I remove the XAxis.TickMode and XAxis.TickText sets from the initialization call.
Any insight into how this port of Plotly works is greatly appreciated.

The axis TickText needs to be mapped to actual values that must be set via TickVals, which you can build from XAxisTicks.Keys. See for reference this and this.

ok, thanks! I'll check them out.

@EricLavault Unfortunately, that did not work. I updated the question with the code I added.
